Calculating forward rate based on semi annual compounding
I am referring to an example in book "Derivatives and Risk Management" by Sundaram Janakiramanan. Page 218.Check the attached image.

I want to understand if the forward rate calculation is correctly done in this example 10.7.
I had been doing the calculation based on how it's done for a different example as described below, but I am not getting the expected answer.
Suppose the yields-to-maturity on a 3-year and 4-year zero coupon bonds are 3.5% and 4% on a semi-annual basis. The “3y1y” implies that the forward rate could be calculated as follows:
A = 6 periods
B = 8 periods
B − A = 2 periods
z6 = 0.035/2 =  0.0175
z8 = 0.04/2 = 0.02
(1+0.0175)^6 × (1+IFR6,2)^2 = (1+0.02)^8
=> IFR6,2 = 0.0275
The “3y1y” implies that the forward rate or forward yield is 5.50% (0.0275% × 2).
Please help!!!
